# Java Hash Map(several values for 1 key)

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

how can I add several values to one key in Hash Map?

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> phonebook = new HashMap<>();
```

For example, I want to `phonebook.put("Mike","123")` `phonebook.put("Mike","321")`
And then I want to get all the values for key Mike.

Comment: Refer to this link https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-duplicate-keys

Comment: You need to add the extra phone numbers to the ```ArrayList```, not to the ```HashMap```.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `computeIfAbsent` for that.

```
phonebook.computeIfAbsent("Mike", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("123");
phonebook.computeIfAbsent("Mike", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("321");
```

Which would avoid checking if a key exists prior to an insert and if concurrency matters that would be an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert values to `ArrayList` like that, you need to initialize it first and than use `add`. You can use `computeIfAbsent`  for that

```
public void addToList(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> phonebook, String key, String value) {
    phonebook.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}

HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> phonebook = new HashMap<>();
addToList(phonebook, "Mike", "123");
addToList(phonebook, "Mike", "321");
```

To get all the values use `get()` to get a list

```
System.out.print(phonebook.get("Mike")); // [123, 321]
```

Or

```
for (String number: phonebook.get("Mike")) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

And to get all the values in the map

```
for (String key: phonebook.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ": ");
    for (String number: phonebook.get(key)) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

[Java's built-in MultivaluedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedHashMap.html)

[Spring's LinkedMultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html)

[Apache's MultivaluedHashMap](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-8.0/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedHashMap.html)